# $x^4 + y^4 = 11^z +13$ has no integer solutions for $z > 0$

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation

> Show that $x^4 + y^4 = 11^z +13$ has no integer solutions for $z > 0$

I have to use division in to cases but again am confused on how to break the cases up. Any input is greatly appreciated!

Comment: mod 5 ..............................

Comment: @WillJagy where is that coming from? what about it?

Comment: @D.Hoffman, Small Fermat.

Answer (score 1):

All the possible numbers modulo 5 can be written in the following form:

$$\{0,\pm1,\pm2\}$$

Squaring them means that every number must have remainder on division by 5 in the following set

$$\{0,1,4\}$$

You can then square them further, to obtain the possible residue classes mod 5 that $n^4$ can be inside.

$$\{0,1\}$$

Bear in mind that $11\ \text{mod}\  5=1 \Rightarrow11^n\ \text{mod} \ 5=1^n=1$

The question then becomes: will adding any two elements from $\{0,1\}$ and adding $-13\ \text{mod 5} \ =2$ ever be congruent to 1 mod 5.

Since there is a small number of cases, you can just try out each possible value and conclude whether there are solutions or not.

You can also notice that the smallest value that adding two elements from $\{0,1\}$ will be $0$ and the largest will be $2$.  Since you have to add $2$, you can conclude that $x^4+y^4-13$ will never be congruent to $1$ mod $5$.